# How to insert data into a relational database using PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo, insert, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to insert data into a relational database.  The schema is below

```
-tags
id
tag

-tagMap
id
img_ID
tag_ID

-images
img_ID
name
url
description
width
height
orientation
color
format
date_taken
camera_make
camera_model
thumb_url
view_count
uploader_ID
sub_ID
upload_date

-users
netID
user_type

-subjects
subject
thumb_ID

-foreign keys
tags:id -> tagMap:tag_ID
images:img_ID -> tagMap:img_ID
images:img_ID -> subjects:thumb_ID
subjects:subject -> images:sub_ID
users:netID -> images:uploaderID
```

However, I'm running into problems with it. I can insert `tags`, which can be used to insert into `tagMap`, but before that I must insert into `images` and therefore must first insert into `users`.

So I think the logic should be `users -> images -> tags -> tagMap`

But I run into a problem with the `subjects`.  I need `subjects` to be filled in order to insert into `images`, but I need `images` to be filled in order to insert into `subjects`.

I've never done relational database design before, so I feel as if there's an error in my design, but I'm not sure.

I'm using PHP's PDO for my connection.

Comment: You need SQL, not PDO. The latter is just a tool to send your SQL to server.

Comment: You have a circular dependency with subjects and images.  Why do you have them referring to each other?  Can you explain (in English, not SQL) what you're trying to accomplish with subjects and images and their relationship?

Comment: Basically, the images table houses the information for said images.  Each image can have a subject.  The subject table houses said subjects and a thumbnail for UI purposes.  The thumbnail references the id of an image that's already in the images table.  Make sense?

Comment: Why do you have images and subjects in two separate tables?  Can an image have multiple subjects and thumbnails?

Comment: The DB is for an image repository.  `images` houses the images for the repository.  `subjects` obviously houses the subjects. An image can only have 1 subject, and a subject can only have 1 thumbnail image.  So I'm associating the thumbnail image with the subject in the `subjects` table.

Comment: perhaps I have overlooked the most obvious answer: have `subjects:thumb_ID` null until after `subjects:subject` has been filled.